# Data is being retrieved, but too late

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```js
    import { Component } from "react";
    import * as firebase from "firebase";

    export class ProfileScreen extends Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Profile",
      };
      state = {
        email: "",
        FirstName: "",
        LastName: "",
        MobileNo: "",
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "",
          authDomain: "",
          databaseURL: "",
          projectId: "",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: "",
          appId: "",
          measurementId: "",
        };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
          firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
        let newPost;
        var id = "OEfxVtMSnLNtvmX8Sv1qgnoHwLX2";
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("/Admin/" + id)
          .once("value", (snapshot) => {
            newPost = snapshot.val();
          });
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            FirstName: newPost.FirstName,
            LastName: newPost.LastName,
            MobileNo: newPost.MobileNo,
          });
          if (newPost.Gender == "Male") {
            this.MchangeCol();
          } else {
            this.FchangeCol();
          }
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
```

Data is being retrieved, but too late and `this.setState` is executing as there is no data in the newPost variable and showing an error that's why I have used `setTimeout` for 10 seconds then the details assigning correctly.

How can I eliminate this `setTimeout` method and sync the data? Please help!

Comment: You can set the values after ```newPost=snapshot.val();``` line. It will work fine.

Comment: thank you  neetin you saved my day

Comment: I am posting as answer so other stumbling on same issue can get the answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values after `newPost=snapshot.val();` line. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that uses the data from the database needs to be inside the `then()` block or be called from there. So the simplest way to solve your problem is to call `setState` from within the `then()` callback:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("/Admin/" + id)
  .once("value", (snapshot) => {
    newPost = snapshot.val();
    this.setState({
      FirstName: newPost.FirstName,
      LastName: newPost.LastName,
      MobileNo: newPost.MobileNo,
    });
  });
```